# convergent series representation for p-adic complex numbers

Tags: cv.complex-variables, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers, induced-representations

The field $\mathbb{C}_p$ of $p$-adic complex numbers is the completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with the corresponding extension of the usual non-Archimedean valuation $|\;\;|_p$.

Every $x\in\mathbb{Q}_p$ has a unique representation of the form $\sum_{i=m}^\infty a_ip^i$, where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and the $a_i$'s are representatives of the classes in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.
Does $y\in\mathbb{C}_p$ have a similar representation as a generalized power series?   Any reference?

Comment: Not only does every element of ${\bf Q}_p$ have such a representation, but every such series represents an element of ${\bf Q}_p$. So there's no room left for non-elements of ${\bf Q}_p$ to be represented as convergent power series in $p$.

Comment: but what about rational exponents?

Comment: Then you're talking about something other than a power series.

Comment: You are right. I am talking about generalized power series. I edited the question.

Comment: There is a paper by David Lampert related to this: https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/26390/0000477.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: @KConrad, in the spirit of preventing link rot, I mention that your paper is Lampert, *Algebraic $p$-adic expansions*, J. Number Theory 23 (1986), no. 3, 279–284 ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=846958)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The blog post http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/08/21/p-adic-fields-for-beginners gives a good overview of the situation.

To briefly summarize (extracted from the above post — any errors are probably mine):

- The elements of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are exactly those represented by series of the form $\sum_{r \in S} a_r p^r$, where $S$ is a bounded-below subset of the integers and each $a_r$ is a multiplicative lift (i.e., a "Teichmüller lift") of an element of $\mathbb{F}_p$.
- The elements of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{nr}$ (the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$) are exactly represented by series of the form $\sum_{r \in S} a_r p^r$, where $S$ is again a bounded-below subset of the integers, but the $a_r$ can now be lifts of any element of $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q$ is a fixed power of $p$. (As explained in the comments below, the $a_r$ cannot be lifts of any elements of $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$; they must all be contained in a common finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$. This constraint is removed in the completion of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{nr}$.)
- The elements of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ and its completion $\mathbb{C}_p$ are represented by certain series of the form $\sum_{r \in S} a_r p^r$, where the $a_r$ are again lifts of elements of $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$, but now $S$ can be a more general well-ordered subset of $\mathbb{Q}$. Which such series give rise to elements of $\mathbb{C}_p$ is discussed in [Kedlaya, *Power series and $p$-adic algebraic closures*](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9906030) ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1845241)).
- The elements of $\Omega_p$, the *spherical completion* of $\mathbb{C}_p$, are represented exactly by series of the form $\sum_{r \in S} a_r p^r$, where the $a_r$ are as before, but now $S$ can be *any* well-ordered subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ (with no other restrictions). This is attributed to the undergraduate thesis of Bjorn Poonen, written up in [Poonen, *Maximally complete fields*](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/amsval.pdf) ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1225257)).

And this is in some sense as far as we can go, since $\Omega_p$ is "maximally complete": we can't extend it any further without "adding geometry", in the sense that it's the unique largest field of characteristic zero with value group $\mathbb{Q}$ and residue field the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: I think that your description of $\mathbb Q_p^{\text{nr}}$ is not quite right (I haven't checked the rest).  For each number individually, the coefficients $a_r$ should probably all come from some fixed finite extension of $\mathbb F_p$, *i.e.*, the field $\mathbb F_p[a_r : r \in S]$ should be a finite extension of $\mathbb F_p$ (although, of course, the extension can be arbitrarily large as we consider different elements of $\mathbb Q_p^{\text{nr}}$).

Comment: @LSpice that's right.  The ring $\mathbf Z_p^{\rm nr}$ is not the same thing as the Witt vectors of $\overline{\mathbf F}_p$: the former require coefficients for each element to come from a finite set of possibilities (depending on the element, as you say), while in the latter there is no such restriction.  For more or less the same reason, $\mathbf Z_p^{\rm nr}$ is not complete and its completion is the Witt vectors of $\overline{\mathbf F}_p$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction; I fixed the description of $\mathbb{Q}_p^{nr}$.